# Sum column values over a window based on a week range (impala)

Tags: sql, datetime, window-functions, impala

Given a table as follows :

```
client_id   date            connections
---------------------------------------
121438297   2018-01-03      0
121438297   2018-01-08      1
121438297   2018-01-10      3
121438297   2018-01-12      1
121438297   2018-01-19      7
363863811   2018-01-18      0
363863811   2018-01-30      5
363863811   2018-02-01      4
363863811   2018-02-10      0
```

I am looking for an efficient way to sum the number of connections that occur within 6 days following the current row (the current row being included in the sum), partitioned by client_id, which would result in :

```
client_id   date            connections     connections_within_6_days
---------------------------------------------------------------------
121438297   2018-01-03      0               1        
121438297   2018-01-08      1               5     
121438297   2018-01-10      3               4     
121438297   2018-01-12      1               1                       
121438297   2018-01-19      7               7
363863811   2018-01-18      0               0
363863811   2018-01-30      5               9
363863811   2018-02-01      4               4
363863811   2018-02-10      0               0
```

Issues :

1. I do not want to add all missing dates and then perform a sliding window counting the 7 following rows because my table is already extremely large.
2. I am using Impala and the `range between interval '7' days following and current row` is not supported.

---

**Edit** : I am looking for a generic answer taking into account the fact that I will need to change the window size to larger numbers (30+ days for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

Impala doesn't fully support `range between`.  Unfortunately, that doesn't leave many options.  One is to use `lag()` with lots of explicit logic:

```
select t.*,
       ( (case when lag(date, 6) over (partition by client_id order by date) = date - interval 6 day
               then lag(connections, 6) over (partition by client_id order by date)
               else 0
          end) +
         (case when lag(date, 5) over (partition by client_id order by date) = date - interval 6 day
               then lag(connections, 5) over (partition by client_id order by date)
               else 0
          end) +
         (case when lag(date, 4) over (partition by client_id order by date) = date - interval 6 day
               then lag(connections, 4) over (partition by client_id order by date)
               else 0
          end) +
         (case when lag(date, 3) over (partition by client_id order by date) = date - interval 6 day
               then lag(connections, 3) over (partition by client_id order by date)
               else 0
          end) +
         (case when lag(date, 2) over (partition by client_id order by date) = date - interval 6 day
               then lag(connections, 2) over (partition by client_id order by date)
               else 0
          end) +
         (case when lag(date, 1) over (partition by client_id order by date) = date - interval 6 day
               then lag(connections, 1) over (partition by client_id order by date)
               else 0
          end) +
         connections
        ) as connections_within_6_days         
from t;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't generalize very well.  If you want a wide range of days, you might want to ask another question.

Comment: thank you @gordon-linoff, I've edited my answer to take the subtlety into account. I've found [something](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d067381c86a258d5b1600fd25beae38d) that could help though I haven't been able to reproduce in Impala.

Comment: @nicholas . . . As this question recommends, you should ask a *new* question.  Your original question was answered.